# SQL Max Pool Reached. C# OPTIMIZE READER

Tags: c#

I need to clode the Connection (conn.Close();) ater reading SQL

Heres the Reader

```
public MySqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        
        MySqlDataReader reader;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        
        return reader;
        


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where do i need to put the Close line?

Answer (score 1):

Either load and return a DataTable using [DataTable.Load(IDataReader)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-5.0) instead of a DataReader, and put the Connection in a `using` block, or use [CommandBehavior.CloseConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) and when the DataReader is closed the Connection will be too.

Comment: Hey, what about a proper `using` block for connection, command and reader?

Comment: With the function that returns DataTable sure.  But when returning a DataReader you can't close the Connection.  The calling code should wrap the returned DataReader in a `using` block.